# Constructive proof of a statement about a property of a Lebesgue-null set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I was studying some measure theory and upon searching for additional exercises on the internet I came upon one that said:

> Given $H$ a Borel set subset of the real numbers, prove that if
> $\lambda(H)=0$ (its Lebesgue measure) then there exists a number
> $\alpha$ such that $\alpha + H$ , the set of all the reals of the form
> $\alpha + h$ where $h \in H$, is a subset of the irrational numbers.

I had no problems in proving this statement, but the proof that I came up with is by contradiction and thus does not find the wanted number (which is not even unique, since it's provable that the set of all such real numbers is a Borel set with measure $+\infty$).

My question is, is it possible to find a constructive proof of this statement? Or maybe is it possible to find such a number for a special non trivial (like one made only of irrational or rational numbers) null set, for example the Cantor set?

Comment: $H'=\cup_{r \in \mathbb Q}(r-H)$ has measure $0$, so there is a  point $\alpha$ which does not belong to it. This $\alpha$ does the job. [$r-H\equiv \{r-h: h \in H\}$].

Comment: That's basically my proof summarised, my question is it possible to give a proof which, in some sense, ables one to compute a number with the said property? Or if such a thing is not generally possible, if there is a specific null set for which such a number can be computed?

Comment: If $H=\{0\}$ then $\alpha =\sqrt 2$ will do.

Comment: Yea I guess I should edit my question to  exclude such trivial examples ahaha

Comment: For the Cantor set in particular, you can definitely write down an explicit $\alpha$ by thinking about base-$3$ expansions. There are some examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/158378).

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look it up

Answer (score 1):

(Of course it depends a bit on what exactly 'constructive' should mean, but)

Take for example $H :=$ all the computable ([or arithmetical, or analytical, ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number)) real numbers, which is countable, so of course Borel and having measure $0$. Then, since rationals are computable and $H$ is a field, $\alpha$ must not belong to $H$, so existence of $\alpha$ is in particular existence of a non-computable number, which can be considered non-constructive